# Pass a C# method group?

Tags: c#, moq, method-group

Is it possible to pass a method group as an argument in C#?

I am using a lot of mocks. I have the following:

```
public static List<IInvocation> InvocationsWithName<T>(
    this Mock<T> mock, string methodName)
    where T: class
{
    var invocations = mock.Invocations
        .Where(i => i.Method.Name == methodName)
        .ToList();

    return invocations;
}
```

I use it like this:

```
var invocations = myInterface
    .InvocationsWithName(nameof(MyInterface.MyMethod));
```

It works. But I would prefer to use it like this:

```
var invocations = myInterface
    .InvocationsWithName(MyInterface.MyMethod);
```

To do that, I need to define my `InvocationsWithName` extension method in a way that accepts `MyInterface.MyMethod` as the argument. But I don't know if/how that can be done.

In practice, MyMethod might be a single method, or it might be a method group with multiple members. Ideally, the solution would work in both cases.

Comment: just use a `Func<T>` instead of a methodName

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain When I do that and try to call it, I get a compile error: "cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'"

Comment: @WilliamJockusch The second parameter of your method `InvocationsWithName` is a string. If you want to pass something else than a string, you have to change the method. I can't think of a defintion, that would accept methods with arbitrary signatures as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your description is a bit vague, but it screams for expressions:

```
static List<IInvocation> InvocationsWithName<TInvocations, TClass, TMethod>(
    this TInvocations mock, TClass @class, Expression<Func<TClass, TMethod>> selector)
    where TInvocations : class, IInvocationsContainer
    where TClass : class
{
    var invocations = mock.Invocations
        .Where(i => i.Method.Name == ((MemberExpression)selector.Body).Member.Name).ToList();
    return invocations;
}

public static void Main()
{
    // called like this
    var invocations = InvocationsWithName(new InvocationsContainer(), new C(), c => c.F);
}
```

Where `C` is the class that contains the function who's name you want to get:

```
class C
{
    public int F { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That appears to make calling the extension method more complicated. My goal is the highest possible ease of calling in the cases I frequently use.

Comment: Perhaps, but safer. You can't give this a random string without a compiler error now.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch actually calling this is pretty easy. In your calling code you jst have this lambda: `c => c.F`. Providing just a string may introduce lots of errors, e.g. the member may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Blindy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74113159/13268855) I would suggest a slightly modified version:

```
public static List<IInvocation> InvocationsByMethodSelector<T>(this Mock<T> mock, Expression<Action<T>> methodSelector)
where T : class
    => mock.Invocations
        .Where(i => i.Method.MethodHandle == ((MethodCallExpression)methodSelector.Body).Method.MethodHandle)
        .ToList();
```

Rather than performing string comparison (`...Name == ...Name`) here we comparing two [`RuntimeMethodHandle` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtimemethodhandle?view=net-5.0)s (`...MethodHandle == ...MethodHandle`)

In case of Blindy's solution the parameter passing looks like this

```
myInterface.InvocationsWithName(m => m.MyMethod);
```

We can't use this because in that case we need to use the `Expression<Func<T, Action>>` for `methodSelector` parameter.

Here the `Expression`'s `Body` is an `UnaryExpression`. It does have a `Method` property, but it is `null` in our case. Its `Operand` property contains the necessary information, but we can't cast that from `Expression` to [`InstanceMethodCallExpressionN`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e55c908229e36f99a52745d4ee85316a0e8bb6a2/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/MethodCallExpression.cs#L198), because that class is `internal`.

So, we need to use `MethodCallExpression` instead which requires us to do the parameter passing like this:

```
myInterface.InvocationsByMethodSelector(m => m.MyMethod());
```